# Select2 Tagging support on Laravel 5.4 not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, tags, jquery-select2, tagging

I created a blog, and put the Tagging system on it, but in the post create page, my tags looks like this:
[tag bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwzT7.png)

This is my HTML code:

```
    <select name="tags[]" id="select2-multi" class="form-control select2-multi" multiple="multiple">
                @foreach($tags as $tag)
                    <option value="{{ $tag->id }}">{{ $tag->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
```

And this is my script:

```
    $('#select2-multi').select2({
        tags: true,
        tokenSeparators: [",", " "],
        multiple: true
    })
```

What can i do to solve this?
Helps

Comment: It seems like you are missing `select2` plugin css file, Are you sure you included css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are missing `select2` plugin css file

Include below css line inside `head` of page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://select2.github.io/dist/css/select2.min.css">
```

Comment: i was using the stylesheet, but i didn't notice that the section stylesheet that i was using it, it didnt existed.. holy such a stupid mistake, thank you very much